# How to know incoming call have video or not in PJSIP in android

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm working on PJSIP in android, How to check incoming call is only audio call or video.?? How identify? I have used below code but it's not working

```
 @Override
    public void onIncomingCall(OnIncomingCallParam prm) {
        System.out.println("======== Incoming call ======== ");
        MyCall call = new MyCall(this, prm.getCallId());
        try {
            CallSetting setting = call.getInfo().getSetting();
            Log.d(" Log APP ", "onIncomingCall: Audio " + setting.getAudioCount() + "  Video" + setting.getVideoCount());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But audio and video count always come 1 but while making call, I have put video 0

```
 MyCall call = new MyCall(account);
        CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam();
        CallSetting setting = new CallSetting();
        setting.setAudioCount(1);
        setting.setVideoCount(0);
        prm.setOpt(setting);
        try {
            call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            call.delete();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

Please tell me hows to identify incoming call has video or not .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of research, I found the PJSIP protocol does not provide caller video count. CallSetting is own setting by all user. Asterisk server does not send call setting to receiver end. But Asterisk id gives information about media support

```
callInfo.getRemOfferer() 
// It returns a boolean value if true then server support video calling.
```

So you can use logic like this

```
long videoCount = (callInfo.getRemOfferer()) ? callInfo.getRemVideoCount() : callInfo.getSetting().getVideoCount();
// if server support video call then check remote server video count value its retrun value in 0,1 format if server not support then chek call setting
```

íf video count is 1 mean this is a video call.

For more details check this [PJSIP Call Setting](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__call__info.htm)

Comment: Hello, I am getting callInfo.getRemOfferer() - true and callInfo.getRemVideoCount() - false in both Audio and Video case. what could be the root cause?

Comment: Got my answer... I was not setting videoCount = 0 in case of audio call. So, don't forget to put VideoCount = 0 in case of audio call and 1 in case of video call.

Answer (score -2):

You need to check the remote details:
sipCall.getInfo().getRemVideoCount()

where "sipCall" is your "call (MyCall)" object.

Comment: you can use own object ;)